# Django, TinyMCE field serialization inconsistencies

Tags: jquery, django, forms, serialization, tinymce-4

In Django I have a form.
There is one form field that has TinyMCE editor attached to it.

I want to check if form has changed so if it has, pop up modal should show.
I achieve this by this code which runs on every page load:

```
$($('my-form').each(function() {
    $(this).data('init') = $(this).serialize();
})
$(window).bind('beforeunload', custom_validator);
);
```

And of course the custom_validator function is in the same file:

```
function custom_validator() {
    $('my-form').each(function() {
        if ($(this).data('init') != $(this).serialize()) {
            return "Form has unsaved changes.";
        }
    })
}
```

When page loads, the data('init') is serialized with the TinyMCE field as well. If the TinyMCE field contains multiple lines, serialize() represents them with '%0D%0A'. Which is fine.
If I want to navigate away from the page or just reload it after changing the form, the 'beforeunload' event triggers the custom_validator function and prevents me to do that which is good as well.

Now, the problem begins when I load the page and I don't make any changes to the form and just want to navigate away from page, the popup window occurs and warns me that there are changes on form, even I didn't change anything.

It turns out that if I have multiple lines on TinyMCE field, when page loads, data('init') contains '%0D%0A' characters, but when I do the serialization of the form in 'custom_validator' function it doesn't include those characters.
Submission of the form works also without any problem.

Any ideas why the two serializer return different serialization strings? It should be the same if the form has not been touched.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that jQuery doesn't serialize properly the content of TinyMCE editor(s).

The reason why on these separated events, namely "load" and "beforeunload", jQuery's serialize method return different content is still a mystery to me. But basically the behavior is that jQuery's serialize method gets confused by the content of form's input filed and TinyMCE editor attached to it.

Like "TEXTAREA" field has different content than TinyMCE editor attached to it, and "SPAN" element can have different content as well on it's inline TinyMCE editor content.

I solved the problem by extending the custom_validator and the anonymous function so that it collects all non TinyMCE fields and TinyMCE editors content separately, serialize and compares them separately.

This way I was able to avoid annoying browser's modal popup window appearance.